# SQL queries involving ' for all'

Tags: sql, plsql, relational-division

I could not get a hint on how to write SQL queries for A and B for the following schema.

```
Programme (Pid:int, Department:string...)
Employee (Eid:int, Department:string..)
Participation (Pid:int, Eid:int, ..)
```

> A. Names of programmes participated by all employees
>
> B. Names of employees participating in all his department's
>   programmes.

Any guidelines would be helpful.

Comment: [See this article](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Comment: And this recent question on optimizing such queries (in Postgres and MySQL). You'll find various ways to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tried these, but this is what I would be thinking:

```
SELECT pg.Name 
FROM Participation AS p INNER JOIN Programme AS pg ON p.Pid = pg.Pid
GROUP BY p.Pid 
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Employeee)



SELECT e.Name 
FROM Participation AS p INNER JOIN Employee AS e ON p.Eid = e.Eid
                        INNER JOIN Programme AS pg ON pg.Pid = p.Pid
WHERE pg.Department = e.Department
GROUP BY p.Eid, e.Department, e.Name
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                   FROM Programme AS pg2 
                   WHERE pg2.Department = e.Department)
```

Comment: Doesn't the group by attributes be the the select for the second query?

Comment: Good catch, just added name to the group by, shouldn't affect the results

Answer (score 3):

The relational operator you require is [division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_.28.C3.B7.29), popularly known as ["the supplier who supplies all parts"](http://www.dbdebunk.com/page/page/772076.htm).

Things to consider are whether [exact division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) or division with remainder and how to handle an empty divisor.

UPDATE: just to clarify, SQL lacks an explicit division operator or keyword**. However, relational division can be achieved in SQL using other operators. I'll refrain from posting a working example because of the 'homework' tag. But the one I usually use is similar to the "Division with Set Operators" example at [this link](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/).

Note that @Dylan Smith's is what is commonly known as "Celko's division" and @tobyodavies's answer uses a variation on what is commonly known as "Date's division" (Date wouldn't use an outer join but instead a second `NOT EXISTS`). But maybe they really did reinvent these well-established approaches themselves, who knows? ;)

** the same applies to many other relational operators e.g. SQL has no semi-difference operator but can be performed using other SQL operators e.g. `NOT IN`, `NOT EXISTS`, `EXCEPT`, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately SQL does not have division...

Comment: @tobyodavies: SQL lacks a division operator or keyword but division can be achieved using other operators. I'll refrain from posting a working example because of the 'homework' tag. But the one I usually use is similar to the "Division with Set Operators" example at [this link](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/). p.s. the same applies to many other relational operators e.g. SQL has no semi-difference operator but can be performed using other SQL operators e.g. `NOT IN`, `NOT EXISTS`, `EXCEPT`, outer join with null filter, etc.

Comment: @tobyodavies: your answer is also a variation on what is commonly called "Date's division", except Date wouldn't use an outer join but a second `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: if that were in your answer it would be an answer to this question...

Answer (score 1):

Use `WHERE NOT EXISTS` and Outer Joins

For all universal Programmes:

```
SELECT * FROM Programme
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM 
                  (Participation NATURAL JOIN Programme) LEFT JOIN Employee
                      USING (Eid,Department) 
                  WHERE Employee.Eid IS NULL)
```

This should be fairly easy to explain - selects all programs where the is no employee not participating

---

For all enthusiatic employees:

```
SELECT * FROM Employee
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM 
                  Employee LEFT JOIN Participation 
                      USING (Eid,department) 
                  WHERE Participation.Eid IS NULL)
```

Again - selects all employyes where there are no programs in the same department in which that employee is not participating.

---

This may look familiar if you are familiar with formal logic at all - universal quantification is generally defined in terms of negated existential qualification